# select from database according to phone number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Guys in a few days I have an exam (midterm), so I am trying to execute every possible  test which could be in midterm, suppose that we have employees  table  where phone number is given in this form  `abc.edf.ghi`  (all these are numbers not strings), how could I  list these employees who's phone number contains `edf?` I dont think that we can use substring function because it is number, am I correct? Also I can't execute division by    sum number like in c++(division by 100,mod  100 and so on,)so please help me, sorry if my  question is too much nonsense. I need just for practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm) `substr` is for string only, but you can use `substr` for columns that are defined as NUMBER datatype,too.

(Assumed that the format of PHONENUMBERCOLUMN is abc.edf.ghi)

`select * from YOURTABLE where substr(PHONENUMBERCOLUMN,5,3)='edf'`

**NOTE:** It should be `'edf'`, not `edf`, if the datatype is other than NUMBER. Always use single quotation marks to be on the safe side, whether the datatype of the column is number or string (char,varchar,varchar2 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't make a mistake of thinking that phone number is a *number*. Phone number is a string which usually consists mainly of digits.

Imagine a phone number beginning with some zeros. If you'd store it as a number they will be truncated while they might be important and might make a difference. Storing it as a string makes it secure.

Additionally, storing it as a string enables you to use SUBSTR and other functions named similarly and doing more or less the same thing, which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can try the [SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function. If the phone number is in the format you show it has to be a varchar not a INT.

For Oracle use [substr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

Comment: it is oracle so  similar is substr  yes?

Comment: and what will be range substr(phonenumber,5,8) or  i have tried but does not work

Comment: shouldn't it be substr(phonenumber,5,3) ?